# How can i target the embed video in wordpress elementor?

Tags: wordpress

I need to add custom javascript to wordpress by targeting the id of the embedded video I attach an example (https://graziafassari.com/vsl/). I have made a script (which target the video by an id and have some logic on behalf of video duration) which is working fine in local HTML so by thinking same I assign the id in elementor but it's not working. so how can i achieve this in WordPress?

Comment: You should check if the id isn't on the container instead the video.

Comment: i checked but its not working can you please check the code i attached below    <script src="https://fast.wistia.com/embed/medias/ypebhkfjp8.jsonp" async></script><script src="https://fast.wistia.com/assets/external/E-v1.js" async></script>
  <div class="wistia_responsive_padding" id="my-video" style="padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative;"><div class="wistia_responsive_wrapper" style="height:100%;left:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;"><div class="wistia_embed wistia_async_ypebhkfjp8 videoFoam=true" style="height:100%;position:relative;width:100%">&nbsp;</div></div></div>

<script>

Comment: <script>
  var vid = document.getElementById("my-video");
  vid.ontimeupdate = function() {myFunction()};
     function myFunction() {
    console.log('duration',Math.round(vid.currentTime))  }
</script>

Comment: Please, in the future, use the code formater. 
Can you check to replace the id in your script by "wistia_simple_video_57"

Comment: sorry for that.i did not get your point you mean i should replace id name with 'wistia_simple_video_57 in script only?

Comment: il your "var vid" declaration

Comment: i added and got an error of not finding

Comment: I guess you are using an iframe, you have to wait your DOM is ready to execute your JS. More info below : https://flaviocopes.com/dom-ready/

Comment: can you please come on my screen i am stuck on this problem ?

Comment: How do you want me to help you ?

Comment: https://files.fm/u/4t3jrzn4z please check the image

Comment: The video is used in this way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  var vid = document.getElementById("wistia_simple_video_57");
  vid.ontimeupdate = function() {myFunction()};
     function myFunction() {
//   if(Math.round(vid.currentTime) > 2){
    console.log('duration',Math.round(vid.currentTime))  }
    //  }

})
```

Comment: where i need to put this id 'wistia_simple_video_57' talking about the video?

Comment: You don't need to, indeed, the video you are calling has already this id.

Comment: getting an error because this id'wistia_simple_video_57' is not finding where I can add this id?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'ontimeupdate')